Is there a way to split context file into multiple files?
I have created SPFx with the React project to achieve custom requirements.
I need to manage 15-20 lists in my SPFx React application.
I have created a context to store those lists of data while the application loads the first time.
My context file is around 1000+ lines. I need to split the context file into different file.
Is there a way to split that file into multiple files?
Thanks

It's not clear what is a "context file". Is it something specific to sharepoint? Usually, you can split any file you want to any number of files.

As far as I know, there is no such function to split context file
